2007 chevrolet malibu ls 2.2l
The remot turn on wire(pink) does not work in my malibu and i connected it to my cig lighter port and now the ports dont work all fuses are good and the power wire has power as well as the ground is working. What could i do to trouble shoot. The radio has a fuse could i just take the remote turn on and the power cord extend eires from them. And connect and disconnect them? When getting in and out?. I testes if the remot turn on works in the raduo by connecting it to the red and white if my car wire and the power wire of the radio. It worked and turned on and everything but it made a buzzing sound a couple times.

I forgot to add the part of where i got a new touch screen radio and need help with the remote turn on wire not working
